# Tracking Read/Write latency for SQL server on linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2019

Hello i want to track SQL server read/write latency for the SQL servers i monitor running on linux host. I checked and found disk related metrics would not work here for linux if fetched from sys.dm_os_performance_counters.

One i found which can be used is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-io-virtual-file-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

However it seems data from that dmv seems cumulative. Is there a better way or solution alreday available if i want to schedule this via SQL agent job and capture metrics over time and graph out the same.

I am aware of 3rd party tools but unfortunately due to small shop app, we do not have budget to get one and for my troubleshooting wanted to implement one for sql servers running on linux hosts

Thank you